# Having issue with substr function in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

```
$geometry = "POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)"
```

I have to split the two decimal values **1.5041909054501184** and **0.39827301781943014** based on space, into an array. For that, as expected, I have to chop-off `'POINT ('` and `')'` from the `$geometry`.

I tried the following lines:

```
$temp = substr($geometry , strpos($geometry, "(")+1, strlen($geometry)-2);
```

and

```
$temp = substr($geometry , strpos($geometry, "(")+1, strpos($geometry, ")")-1);
```

Echoing `$temp` in both the cases displays string as:

```
"1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)"
```

How can I remove the `')'` from the string `$geometry`?

**UPDATE**

How can I generalize it to strings like these?

```
$geometry = "POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)";
```

and

```
$geometry = "POLYGON ((1.5049088554391572 0.39805485932781448, 1.5049135685638309 0.39805660717232405, 1.5049147247575003 0.39805462248168044, 1.5049101547531727 0.39805287533491257, 1.5049088554391572 0.39805485932781448))";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = 'POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)';
// Remove any character that is not digit, dot or space, then trim whitespace
$stripped = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9 \.]/', '', $str));
// Split by the space in the middle
$exploded = explode(' ', $stripped);

print_r($exploded);
/*
  Array
  (
      [0] => 1.5041909054501184
      [1] => 0.39827301781943014
  )
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a regular expression:

```
$geometry = "POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)";
preg_match_all('/POINT \((\d\.\d+) (\d\.\d+)/ ', $geometry, $matches);

$matches[1][0]; // => "1.1.5041909054501184"
$matches[2][0]; // => "0.39827301781943014"
```

Note that these results are strings, you'll have to cast them to floats to use them as floats.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not just remove them?

```
$geometry = "POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)";
$temp1 = str_replace("POINT (", "", $geometry);
$temp = str_replace(")", "", $temp1);
```

Assuming your geometry syntax is always the same, this will do just fine.

Also, since you're starting 7 characters in advance, and you want to chop the last one, give the `$length` argument a value of `length-8`:

```
$temp = substr($geometry , strpos($geometry, "(")+1, strlen($geometry)-8);
```

Both of these echo correctly.

---

### Edit!

Based on the comments:

Try this one:

```
$temp = preg_replace("|.+\((.+)\)|", "$1", $geometry);
```

Comment: Strange, but `str_replace()` did not replace the `')'` from the string. Also the string before the `'('` is not the same always.

Comment: Did you try the code I pasted? I tested it. Also, if it's not always the same, please give a general input example in your question. Otherwise it will always fail on this other possible syntax.

Comment: Yes. I did try your code. The general syntax will be like POLYGON, POLYLINE, LINESTRING etc. in place of POINT and any even number of decimal values within `"("` and `")"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better with `preg_replace` ?

```
$geometry = "POINT (1.5041909054501184 0.39827301781943014)";

echo preg_replace('/POINT \((.*?)\)/uis','$1',$geometry);
```

Comment: This also worked. But can it be generalized as I mentioned in my updated question?

Comment: Alright. I converted your solution to `echo preg_replace('/[A-Z]+ \(+(.*?)\)+/uis','$1',$geometry);`. Now it is generalized.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to substr is not "end point" but "substring length".

So you need to say:

```
$start_pos = strpos($geometry, "(")+1;
$temp = substr($geometry , $start_pos , strlen($geometry)-$start_pos);
```

Then you can use `explode` to get the two decimals;

`list($x, $y) = explode(' ', $temp);`

or

`$coordArray = explode(' ', $temp);`

Answer (score 0):

The 3d parameter should be the length of the substring, not the position in the original string

Comment: In my second line of code, I have to tried to find the position of `")"`. See this: `$temp = substr($geometry , strpos($geometry, "(")+1, strpos($geometry, ")")-1);`.

Comment: That's right, but if your write "POINT (123 456)" and want to select the string from index 7 till index 14, then you should use substr($geometry, 7, 14-7), IE the string starting at 7 that is 7 characters long. Instead, you're asking for the string starting at 7 that is 14 characters long.
It's like the substr() and substring() methods in javascript...